# Issue with positioning an absolute div

Tags: html, css, coding-style, styles, stylesheet

Hey guys I am having trouble styling my navigation so that is will always be at the same position on a page no matter the browser....

I have the following:

```
#Mainmenu {
    width: 44%;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: .9em;
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 35em;
    top: 4.7em;
    right: 0;   

}
```

This is positioned, exacly where I want it in chrome and firefox but not in IE.  Also if I change resolution it changes the positioning a little.  I want to know how I can always have it at the same spot it is suppose to.

Let me know if you need anything else!

David

update:

http://jsfiddle.net/MVpkP/ - is the styles that I have in it and the layout.

[image: this is what it looks like in IE]
[image: What it looks like in Chrome]

The one above this is Chrome and the one I want it to remain like, that's how I want it styled.

Comment: Can you jsfiddle it so that we can test it out in IE?

Comment: what information do you want?

Comment: just put the code http://jsfiddle.net here the relevant code so that we can test it out...

Comment: @arpitSrivastava I added it, but thats not really how it looks.

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava I just added images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in your header

```
 <!--[if IE]>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="IE.css" />
 <![endif]-->
```

Create an additional css file for IE and adjust your IE css accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

you should either use % on your left/right/top, or put this element inside another element.

for example:

```
#Mainmenu {
width: 44%;
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: .9em;
list-style: none;
position: absolute;
left: 3%;
top: 1.5%;
right: 0;   
}
```

As for putting it in another element:

```
#wrap{
width: 700px;
margin:0 auto;  
 }

<div class="wrap">
     your menu stuff...
</div>
```

either of those should solve your problem

Comment: The top one did not work for me...what do you mean for the wrap one?

Comment: if you set a wrapper element. and then use absolute on inside element without stating top/right/left it will be absolute, but will be relative to the wrapper element. and if you'll want to change its position you can then margin-left/ right.

Comment: would the <!--[if IE]>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="IE.css" />
 <![endif]--> be easier?

Comment: this will also work its up to your preference in many cases a separate css files is required, i just prefer trying to have 1 css file.